# ERROR in app.js from UglifyJs Dom7, Webpack, Framework7, TS

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I am using Typescript together with Framework7, Webpack, ES5 etc.

```
{
      "name": "f7-cnode",
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "description": "Framework7, Webpack and Babel",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.config.js -d --colors --inline",
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js -p --colors --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout"
      },
      "author": "Nic",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "framework7": "^2.1.3",
        "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
        "less": "^3.0.1",
        "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",
        "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
        "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2",
        "webpack-dev-server-proxy": "0.0.8"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "date-fns": "^1.28.0",
        "node-polyglot": "^2.2.2"
      }
    }
```

The following command executes normally:

```
npm run dev
```

and I am able to run it in the browser and everything works fine. But when I try to build it with:

```
npm run build
```

this command causes an error:

```
            $ npm run build

            > f7-cnode@2.2.0 build C:\wamp64\www\Cordova\Cordova-ts\1
            > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js -p --colors --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout

            Hash: bf98e84f9caf99c38ba5
            Version: webpack 3.10.0
            Time: 12844ms
             5 assets

            ERROR in app.js from UglifyJs
            Unexpected token: name (Dom7) [app.js:749,6]

            ERROR in app.js from UglifyJs
            Unexpected token: name (Dom7) [app.js:749,6]
            Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
                 1 asset
            Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!src/assets/css/icons.css:
                 2 assets
            Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js!src/assets/app.less:
                 1 asset
            npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
            npm ERR! errno 2
            npm ERR! f7-cnode@2.2.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js -p --colors --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout`
            npm ERR! Exit status 2
            npm ERR!
            npm ERR! Failed at the f7-cnode@2.2.0 build script.
            npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     C:\Users\ThinkIT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-27T10_53_58_787Z-debug.log
```

I have been struggling with this all day and I can't get rid of this error.

Any ideas how could I solve this?

Comment: add app.js code. that's where error is.

Comment: app.js file is the file that should have been created if everything went successful. But there was an error while creating (npm run build) that file and I didn't get it at the end, because it has never been created.